# SharePoint 2016 Teamsite Issues

Tags: 2016, team-sites

I need some help here. We installed SharePoint 2016 (2 WEB, 2 App, 2 DC and 2 Search). Created a publishing site collection which opens up fine without any issues.

But, when I create a Team Site collection, it comes back as blank. Not a blanksite, but just blank. I am able to navigate to viewlsts.aspx but, when I try to navigate to settings.aspx, its blank again.

We have pretty much not done anything on the site. Just created webapp and site collections. Any help is much appreciated. This is not going anywhere. Looking forward for some direction.

Attached the fiddler [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bye6EhhhWLn0UkRIamVVQ3Uxajg)

Comment: Try a different browser (Chrome or FF). What does the F12 developer console indicate in the Console tab?

Comment: And what does F12 indicate? Or Fiddler?

Comment: There's got to be more than that. Edit your post with a complete Fiddler log. Can't help you with the current information you've provided. Make sure you specify if there is a load balancer and/or proxy in front of SharePoint, any ULS or Event Viewer logs that may be applicable, etc.

Comment: Attached the fiddler logs

Comment: We have two WFE that is load balanced. There is absolutely nothing that comes up in the event viewer.Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue Resolved. 
It was an SSL offloading issue. Once the AAM was set right, everything was working as expected.
Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be issue with feature called Fast Site Collection Creation. I guess that Fast Site Collection is enabled, but there are no sitemaster.
Try to create one as described e.g. here: http://nikcharlebois.com/sharepoint-2016-fast-site-creation/
But it can be something else. ULS should give you an answer.